# My drupal only runs when I'm online

Tags: linux, drupal, ubuntu, localhost, ubuntu-10.04

Hey, I'm using ubuntu 10.04, and when I try to run online on localhost without being connected on internet, it doesn't run. It only runs when I'm connected on internet.

Everything is installed right, mysql, apache, bla bla bla, etc.

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm, that you are able to connect to your database using the same host name as specified in settings.php: `$db_url`. If it says `mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename`, then you should be able to connect to MySQL using `mysql -u username -h localhost -p`. If it fails, try `127.0.0.1` instead of localhost.
Besides, please describe your problem in more detail to get additional help.

Comment: It Worked!! I was trying to acces by localhost, and I tryied by 127.0.0.1/drupal and it worked. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a very long timeout, it could be the update status module. Disable that and try again.

Some more information about what happens when you try to open your site would be helpful.